# How to find field when after populate in mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have code:

```
 schemeProductDetailsModel.find({})
        .populate({
            path: 'schemeProduct',
            model: schemeProductsMd
          })
        .populate({
            path: 'qrCode',
            model: qrcodesMd,
            match : {code : "TB00006"}
        })
        .exec();
```

and it's return:

```
[
        {
            "note": "ghi chú",
            "_id": "5adecfc654c19a0014f55032",
            "schemeProduct": {
                "quantityDeployed": 0,
                "quantityRemaining": 10,
                "_id": "5a7d089efeb222491ae36f9a",
                "product": "5a7bbf5bfeb222491acd2b54",
                "quantityDeploy": 10,
                "updatedAt": "2018-03-08T03:29:13.379Z"
            },
            "qrCode": {
                "_id": "5a7a6c89f36d283d3de73459",
                "code": "TB00006",
                "status": "5a7a6f07feb222491ab93fac"
            },
            "serial": "SR001",
            "dateFrom": "2018-04-24T00:00:00.000Z",
            "dateTo": "2018-04-25T00:00:00.000Z",
            "createdAt": "2018-04-24T06:33:42.032Z",
            "updatedAt": "2018-04-24T06:33:42.032Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
   ]
```

and I want find fields `"code"` in collection mongoDB:
I want return when find `"qrCode.code" : "TB00006"` and if find `"qrCode.code" : "TB00007"` then return

```
[]
```

I hope you help me....
Thank you
Sorry My English is bad. :(

Comment: Did you make your request with `TB00006` or with `TB00007` ? it's not clear

Comment: sorry my english is bad. Code not working when i find({'qrCode.code' : 'TB00007') :((((

Comment: No problem, with the data you show after populate, there a not `qrCode.code` that is equal to `TB00007`, so it's normal that you have a empty result, try with `TB00006`

Comment: Hic. I want find TB00007 and it's must return [].. but when find TB00007 then It still returns as above....So bad :(

Comment: ah ok, I was not understanding your problem. I've never use Mongoose, but with what I see in the documentation, I think you need to place your query in the `match` of the second populate call. If your already do this I don't know :/

Comment: huhu.... not working :(((( Who can help me? :((((